# No se activa el método consume()

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

Buenos días tengo el siguiente código donde necesito que al escribir en un txtField en javafx no se acepten espacios en blanco, pero el método consume() no se activa, ¿hay alguna otra forma de evitar que se escriba el espacio en blanco?

```
    void eventoTeclado(KeyEvent event) {
    
       Object evento=event.getSource();     
    
       if(evento.equals(txtUsuario)) {
        
        // Evaluamos si lo que se introdujo es un espacio en blanco
        if (event.getCharacter().equals(" ")) {             
            
            event.consume();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías limitarte a editar el campo de texto después de que se pierda el foco y quitarle los espacios

Te hago el ejemplo en consola, pero lo podrías adaptar sin problemas a los formularios

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
//para la prueba pedimos un texto por teclado con espacios, tu lo que harías sería capturar el texto del textField
System.out.println("texto");
//almacenamos el texto en la variable texto
String texto = teclado.nextLine();

//editamos la variable texto, eliminamos los espacios en blanco y almacenamos el nuevo texto en la variable nTexto      
String nTexto = texto.replace(" ","");
//imprimimos el nuevo texto por consola, tu lo que harías sería reescribir el textField con el nuevo texto
System.out.println(nTexto);
```

Answer (score 1):

porque tu evento se llama `void eventoTeclado`? Me suena a que no estas agregando un evento, bueno de todos modos no se usar muy bien JavaFX, pero hice una prueba rápida con el código de la pagina de Oracle, y tu comprobación esta bien, pero yo lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
final TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setPromptText("Write here");
textField.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 34;");

textField.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            
        if(ke.getCharacter().equals(" ")) {
            ke.consume();
        }
            
        //console.getItems().add(ke.getText());
    }
});
```

Y anda bien para mi, el TextField no escribe los espacios.